# Can only connect to a network for a short period of time; restarting my computer is the only way to allow me to reconnect

Tags: networking, windows-8

So this recently starting happening, my computer would randomly drop connection to my home's network. It is only my computer that gets dropped from the network. So far, **the only thing that has allowed me to reconnect to the network is restarting my computer.**

**Here is what I have done so far, but done of this has fixed it permanently:**

Restart/Power cycle Router

Run windows diagnostic tests on networking

Forgetting the network and reconnecting

Refreshing my PC

Full wipe (reset) of my PC

Unchecked the box on the network adapter setting that can disable the adapter if it wants to save power (power management tab)

Ran a tracert command to an IP of a game server (initially thought it may have been the game server issue so i checked all of the "hops" and they were fine. If someone wants me to post a picture of any of the command prompt commands I can do that)

Ran something along the lines of ipconfig refresh in command prompt

Ran something along the lines of /scannow in command prompt. It found corrupt files and this is what prompted the refresh and reset of my PC.

**What I am currently trying now but don't know how to do:**

Looking for where McAfee Personal Firewall BS is and disabling all of that.

**What I haven't done:**

Anything hardware related

Another /scannow post-reset

**Technical info:**

Acer Aspire

Intel core i7

RAM 6GB

64-bit Windows 8 OS

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager -> The Network adapter in Question -> Choose Properties. Now click Details.
Property Hardware IDs will provide something like VEN_1814&DEV_3290. Now get the correct drivers for that specific device.

Comment: This is an answer on how to find drivers for a device. Since OP hasn't specifically asked about that, this is more of a way to troubleshoot than to fix the issue than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have two devices on your network offering DHCP addresses, like two routers connected together somehow.  It could be that the correct device is offering an address, but then an incorrectly configured device is offering an incorrect address.   If you have multiple devices on your network, see if the problem persists when everything else is disconnected, and then start adding things back gradually over time.

Another thing to check is to make sure that two devices aren't using the same network address.  The troubleshooting is similar - eliminate all other devices and add them back gradually to narrow it down.

Your Windows event log will show more information if there is an address conflict with another device on the network.  `ipconfig /all` from a command prompt will show your current network settings for you to check.